# How to open Cash drawer which is connected via RJ11 from receipt printer

Tags: vb.net, printing

My VB.NET application is stuck with an issue.

How can I open a cash drawer from my vb.net application after I press a button ?
Cash drawer is connected to E-POS Recept printer via RJ11 port.

When I contacted E-POS support, they have sent me a control code to be used for open cash drawer.
Which is chr(27)+chr(112)+chr(0)+chr(50)+chr(250)

I don't know how to implement this code in my application event.

I tried to open it through the codes from different sources.
I would be thankful if you could help to move from this stage.

Thanks

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/EN-US/kb/154078

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I use:

RawPOSPrinter class

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Drawing.Printing
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Public Class RAWPOSPrinter
' Structure and API declarions:
<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)> _
Structure DOCINFOW
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> Public pDocName As String
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> Public pOutputFile As String
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> Public pDataType As String
End Structure

<DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint:="OpenPrinterW", _
   SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode, _
   ExactSpelling:=True, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)> _
Public Shared Function OpenPrinter(ByVal src As String, ByRef hPrinter As IntPtr, ByVal pd As Long) As Boolean
End Function
<DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint:="ClosePrinter", _
   SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode, _
   ExactSpelling:=True, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)> _
Public Shared Function ClosePrinter(ByVal hPrinter As IntPtr) As Boolean
End Function
<DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint:="StartDocPrinterW", _
   SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode, _
   ExactSpelling:=True, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)> _
Public Shared Function StartDocPrinter(ByVal hPrinter As IntPtr, ByVal level As Int32, ByRef pDI As DOCINFOW) As Boolean
End Function
<DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint:="EndDocPrinter", _
   SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode, _
   ExactSpelling:=True, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)> _
Public Shared Function EndDocPrinter(ByVal hPrinter As IntPtr) As Boolean
End Function
<DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint:="StartPagePrinter", _
   SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode, _
   ExactSpelling:=True, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)> _
Public Shared Function StartPagePrinter(ByVal hPrinter As IntPtr) As Boolean
End Function
<DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint:="EndPagePrinter", _
   SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode, _
   ExactSpelling:=True, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)> _
Public Shared Function EndPagePrinter(ByVal hPrinter As IntPtr) As Boolean
End Function
<DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint:="WritePrinter", _
   SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode, _
   ExactSpelling:=True, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)> _
Public Shared Function WritePrinter(ByVal hPrinter As IntPtr, ByVal pBytes As IntPtr, ByVal dwCount As Int32, ByRef dwWritten As Int32) As Boolean
End Function

' SendBytesToPrinter()
' When the function is given a printer name and an unmanaged array of  
' bytes, the function sends those bytes to the print queue.
' Returns True on success or False on failure.
Public Shared Function SendBytesToPrinter(ByVal szPrinterName As String, ByVal pBytes As IntPtr, ByVal dwCount As Int32) As Boolean
    Dim hPrinter As IntPtr      ' The printer handle.
    Dim dwError As Int32        ' Last error - in case there was trouble.
    Dim di As DOCINFOW          ' Describes your document (name, port, data type).
    Dim dwWritten As Int32      ' The number of bytes written by WritePrinter().
    Dim bSuccess As Boolean     ' Your success code.

    ' Set up the DOCINFO structure.
    di = New DOCINFOW
    With di
        .pDocName = "RAW DOC"
        .pDataType = "RAW"
    End With
    ' Assume failure unless you specifically succeed.
    bSuccess = False
    If OpenPrinter(szPrinterName, hPrinter, 0) Then
        If StartDocPrinter(hPrinter, 1, di) Then
            If StartPagePrinter(hPrinter) Then
                ' Write your printer-specific bytes to the printer.
                bSuccess = WritePrinter(hPrinter, pBytes, dwCount, dwWritten)
                EndPagePrinter(hPrinter)
            End If
            EndDocPrinter(hPrinter)
        End If
        ClosePrinter(hPrinter)
    End If
    ' If you did not succeed, GetLastError may give more information
    ' about why not.
    If bSuccess = False Then
        dwError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()
    End If
    Return bSuccess
End Function ' SendBytesToPrinter()

' SendFileToPrinter()
' When the function is given a file name and a printer name, 
' the function reads the contents of the file and sends the
' contents to the printer.
' Presumes that the file contains printer-ready data.
' Shows how to use the SendBytesToPrinter function.
' Returns True on success or False on failure.
Public Shared Function SendFileToPrinter(ByVal szPrinterName As String, ByVal szFileName As String) As Boolean
    ' Open the file.
    Dim fs As New FileStream(szFileName, FileMode.Open)
    ' Create a BinaryReader on the file.
    Dim br As New BinaryReader(fs)
    ' Dim an array of bytes large enough to hold the file's contents.
    Dim bytes(fs.Length) As Byte
    Dim bSuccess As Boolean
    ' Your unmanaged pointer.
    Dim pUnmanagedBytes As IntPtr

    ' Read the contents of the file into the array.
    bytes = br.ReadBytes(fs.Length)
    ' Allocate some unmanaged memory for those bytes.
    pUnmanagedBytes = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(fs.Length)
    ' Copy the managed byte array into the unmanaged array.
    Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, pUnmanagedBytes, fs.Length)
    ' Send the unmanaged bytes to the printer.
    bSuccess = SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pUnmanagedBytes, fs.Length)
    ' Free the unmanaged memory that you allocated earlier.
    Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pUnmanagedBytes)
    Return bSuccess
End Function ' SendFileToPrinter()

' When the function is given a string and a printer name,
' the function sends the string to the printer as raw bytes.
Public Shared Sub SendStringToPrinter(ByVal szPrinterName As String, ByVal szString As String)
    Dim pBytes As IntPtr
    Dim dwCount As Int32
    ' How many characters are in the string?
    dwCount = szString.Length()
    ' Assume that the printer is expecting ANSI text, and then convert
    ' the string to ANSI text.
    pBytes = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemAnsi(szString)
    ' Send the converted ANSI string to the printer.
    SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pBytes, dwCount)
    Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pBytes)
End Sub
End Class
```

Open drawer class

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class CashDrawer

#Region "DECLARATIONS"
Private Shared OPEN_CODE As String = Chr(27) & "p" & Chr(0) & Chr(100) & Chr(250)
#End Region

#Region "PROPERTIES"

#End Region

#Region "USER-DEFINED"

#End Region

#Region "METHODS"
Public Shared Sub OpenDrawer(ByVal cDrawer As String)
    Try
        RAWPOSPrinter.SendStringToPrinter(cDrawer, OPEN_CODE)
    Catch ex As Exception
        ErrMsg(ex)
    End Try
End Sub

Public Shared Sub OpenDrawer(ByVal cDrawer As String, ByVal cOpenString As String)
    Try
        RAWPOSPrinter.SendStringToPrinter(cDrawer, cOpenString)
    Catch ex As Exception
        ErrMsg(ex)
    End Try
End Sub
#End Region

End Class
```

Create a printer in Devices and Printers. Select type, Generic/Text Only. Name the printer. Pass the printer name when calling the above function to open the drawer.

Comment: Thank you very much