# Epson TM-T88V printer drawer kick

Tags: c#, point-of-sale

My client has bought a new Cash Drawer for his POS system. 
Features fo the cash drawer as follows:

> Model: D41SRB
>   SKU: D41SRB
>   Electronic Cash Drawer Black 16",
>   Roller, 24V Epson STD RJ11, Stainless front
>   5 Bill/5 Coin
>   1mm steel case
>   Two extra brackets inside top of case for added durability`

Its connected to the reciept printer `EPSON TM-T88V Receipt`.
I need to open this drawer from a click of button in my C# application, however when I set the drawer to open after print from Printer Preference it works. So , I am sure its connected fine. I need something similar to this [ARTICLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40203442/how-to-open-cash-drawer-which-is-connected-via-rj11-from-receipt-printer) but in C#.
So please help

Comment: FWIW You can convet C# <-> VB.Net pretty reliably online. https://www.carlosag.net/tools/codetranslator/ is one example. If it's anything like the cash drawers I sued to interact with, you needed to send a certain stream of characters to the (parallel/serial) port. Should be the same logic as printing a plain text string [Edit: Better converter link which supports this code]

Comment: Here are some other ways to to this. I’ve done it before in c# so later on I might be able to give you that code. http://www.beaglehardware.com/howtoprogramcashdrawer.html

Comment: @theMayer how do I use those in c#, any code example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to solve my issue I used

> RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter("EPSON TM-T88V Receipt", System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(new byte[] { 27, 112, 48, 55, 121 }));

got this drawer code from http://keyhut.com/popopen.htm

Heres My whole code:

```
 public class RawPrinterHelper
    {
        // Structure and API declarions:
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public class DOCINFOA
        {
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
            public string pDocName;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
            public string pOutputFile;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
            public string pDataType;
        }
        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "OpenPrinterA", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool OpenPrinter([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string szPrinter, out IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pd);

        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "ClosePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool ClosePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "StartDocPrinterA", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool StartDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, Int32 level, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] DOCINFOA di);

        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "EndDocPrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool EndDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "StartPagePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool StartPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "EndPagePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool EndPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "WritePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool WritePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount, out Int32 dwWritten);

        // SendBytesToPrinter()
        // When the function is given a printer name and an unmanaged array
        // of bytes, the function sends those bytes to the print queue.
        // Returns true on success, false on failure.
        public static bool SendBytesToPrinter(string szPrinterName, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount)
        {
            Int32 dwError = 0, dwWritten = 0;
            IntPtr hPrinter = new IntPtr(0);
            DOCINFOA di = new DOCINFOA();
            bool bSuccess = false; // Assume failure unless you specifically succeed.

            di.pDocName = "RAW Document";
            // Win7
            di.pDataType = "RAW";

            // Win8+
            // di.pDataType = "XPS_PASS";

            // Open the printer.
            if (OpenPrinter(szPrinterName.Normalize(), out hPrinter, IntPtr.Zero))
            {
                // Start a document.
                if (StartDocPrinter(hPrinter, 1, di))
                {
                    // Start a page.
                    if (StartPagePrinter(hPrinter))
                    {
                        // Write your bytes.
                        bSuccess = WritePrinter(hPrinter, pBytes, dwCount, out dwWritten);
                        EndPagePrinter(hPrinter);
                    }
                    EndDocPrinter(hPrinter);
                }
                ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
            }
            // If you did not succeed, GetLastError may give more information
            // about why not.
            if (bSuccess == false)
            {
                dwError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            }
            return bSuccess;
        }

        public static bool SendFileToPrinter(string szPrinterName, string szFileName)
        {
            // Open the file.
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(szFileName, FileMode.Open);
            // Create a BinaryReader on the file.
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
            // Dim an array of bytes big enough to hold the file's contents.
            Byte[] bytes = new Byte[fs.Length];
            bool bSuccess = false;
            // Your unmanaged pointer.
            IntPtr pUnmanagedBytes = new IntPtr(0);
            int nLength;

            nLength = Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length);
            // Read the contents of the file into the array.
            bytes = br.ReadBytes(nLength);
            // Allocate some unmanaged memory for those bytes.
            pUnmanagedBytes = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(nLength);
            // Copy the managed byte array into the unmanaged array.
            Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, pUnmanagedBytes, nLength);
            // Send the unmanaged bytes to the printer.
            bSuccess = SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pUnmanagedBytes, nLength);
            // Free the unmanaged memory that you allocated earlier.
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pUnmanagedBytes);
            fs.Close();
            fs.Dispose();
            fs = null;
            return bSuccess;
        }
        public static bool SendStringToPrinter(string szPrinterName, string szString)
        {
            IntPtr pBytes;
            Int32 dwCount;
            // How many characters are in the string?
            dwCount = szString.Length;
            // Assume that the printer is expecting ANSI text, and then convert
            // the string to ANSI text.
            pBytes = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemAnsi(szString);
            // Send the converted ANSI string to the printer.
            SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pBytes, dwCount);
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pBytes);
            return true;
        }
    }
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter("EPSON TM-T88V Receipt", System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(new byte[] { 27, 112, 48, 55, 121 }));
    }
```

After this by clicking on button1 it kicks the drawer.

Answer (score 1):

To open the drawer on the TM-T88 series, you have to have it connected via a serial or network port.

The following command sequence is what I used. This is really old code, but it should do the job. You have to open the port and initialize the printer before doing anything else, so that's in there too.

```
private SerialPort serialPort1 = new SerialPort();

public void OpenPort()
{
    serialPort1.PortName = "COM1";
    serialPort1.Encoding = Encoding.ASCII;
    serialPort1.BaudRate = 38400;
    serialPort1.Parity = System.IO.Ports.Parity.None;
    serialPort1.DataBits = 8;
    serialPort1.StopBits = System.IO.Ports.StopBits.One;
    serialPort1.DtrEnable = true;
    serialPort1.Open();
}

public void InitializePrinter()
{
    serialPort1.Write(Char.ConvertFromUtf32(27) + char.ConvertFromUtf32(64));
}

public void OpenDrawer()
{
    serialPort1.Write(char.ConvertFromUtf32(27) +
       char.ConvertFromUtf32(112) + 
       char.ConvertFromUtf32(0) +
       char.ConvertFromUtf32(5) + 
       char.ConvertFromUtf32(5));
}
```

Comment: Drawer is connected to printer via RJ11. How can I determine which port its connected to?

Comment: You need to specify the _printer_ port in the program.  Above program instructs the _printer_ to activate the cash drawer that is connected to the RJ11 port.

Comment: Along with this- you may have to install some software from Epson if it’s connected via Ethernet. This is all really beyond the scope of what Stack overflow is useful for though.

Comment: When I checked port no. from Printer Propeties it has "ESDPRT001" checked so I tried opening that port but it gave me an error

Comment: @mark- I hate to say this, but you seem to be in well over your head here, and I don't think I can provide much more help. Some of this is stuff you'll have to figure out on your own.

Comment: @theMayer sorry for delay response, was trying few things none worked. I found code for TM-T88V to open cash drawer ie;27,112,48,55,121, should I replace this in `OpenDrawer()` function?

Comment: Sure. I think the last couple of arguments are time parameters.

Answer (score 0):

assume your serial port is called "port".

Just use: port.writeLine("\x10\x14\x01\x00\x08");  // For Cash Drawer 0

Just use: port.writeLine("\x10\x14\x01\x01\x08");  // For Cash Drawer 1

as the printer can talk to 2 cash drawers.

Commands:

ASCII    DCE   DC4   n    m    t

Hex      10    14    n    m    t

Decimal  16    20    n    m    t

Where n = 1, m = 0 or 1 (cash drawer #), t <= 1, t <=8