# POS thermal printer drawer kicks only first time

Tags: linux, printing, cups, pos

I'm using the `lp` command to print stuff to a thermal POS printer. All works fine when I'm printing formatted text and doing cuts.. etc. However, when I send the Drawer Kick command `ESC p 0 25 250` it kicks the drawer and then I cannot print or kick after that without having to reset the printer.

Has anyone had this problem and do you know the fix?

What I've noted is all the commands that I send to the printer have a start command and an end. For example, to turn bold text on I have 
`ESC E \x01` and to turn it off I have `ESC E \0`, `\0` being the null character. But the drawer kick command doesn't have the null character at the end, could that be screwing the printer queue for some reason? Maybe printer is expecting an end to the command somehow?

Can anyone help please?

Comment: I assume that you are aware that the number sequences you list after `ESC p` are numeric equivalent value of 2 characters and not a string of characters?  you may  want to reference this solution [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49053778/epson-tm-t88v-printer-drawer-kick]

Comment: Not sure what you exactly mean but the command is supposed to be 'ESC p m t1 t2' where m is 0 or 1 and t1 and t2 are numeric values to denote signal ON and signal OFF, respectively, in milliseconds (multiplied by two)

Comment: not sure how you are generating your codes to send to the printer.  The hexidecimal equivalent to the string of characters you should send is '\0x1b \0x70 \0x0 \0x19 \0xef'  based on your original info and what I see from external documentation.

Comment: Oh yeah I am actually sending the string in hex.

Comment: Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*

Comment: @jww are you saying my question isn't clear or that it doesn't include a desired behaviour? If that's what you're saying then Stackoverflow is becoming more and more of an unwelcoming environment! I don't know how much clearer you want me to be, or what else Stackoverflow is for these days if my question is not a perfectly valid SO-worth question!

Comment: Or if your English isn't good enough to understand the question, then I'm sorry I cannot really fill in a template for you to outline "problem statement, expected behaviour, what has been tried... etc" in different sections for you to read.